# Process.start is not working when code is hosted on IIS

Tags: asp.net-core

I want to open notepad file by `process.start` when I debug the code locally it is working fine. But when I host my API on IIS it is not working I already give all the permission to my Site on IIS.

I give all the permission to my hosted Website.

```
Process.Start("C:\\Windows\\notepad.exe");
return Ok("DONE");
```

There is No error or exception `coming.API` run correctly.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: did you solve this?